# Why isn't clicking on an audio track immediately triggering play?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I have a [StackBlitz minimum code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-server-mrgppz?file=context%2Faudio.context.js) which illustrates the problem. For brevity, I've also placed the problematic code below.

Whenever the user clicks on a `track` of a number of `tracks`, I want the `Audio` component to immediately play that `track`, think Spotify etc.

Currently, the `source` of the `audio` component is updating, but it does not `play` the track unless there is a ***triple* click**.

I'm not sure why a triple click is needed to create a successful play call.

---

```
const changeSource = newSource => {
    setSource(newSource);
    togglePlayPause();
  };
```

Here is the `setSource` hook, which is initialised to a default track:

```
const [source, setSource] = useState(
    'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-4.mp3'
  );
```

```
  const togglePlayPause = () => {
    const prevValue = isPlaying;
    setIsPlaying(!prevValue);
    if (!prevValue) {
      audioPlayer.current.play();
    } else {
      audioPlayer.current.pause();
    }
  };
```

Comment: Could it possibly be playing but there's just a delay as it buffers up or something?

Comment: _"...think Spotify etc."_ - They also have to buffer a bunch of bits before they can play anything.

Comment: There is something that does not convince me: let's say `isPlaying` is `true` and you trigger `changeSource()`; `changeSource()` would call `togglePlayPause()` which, in its turn, will set `isPlaying` to `false`; is that the intended behaviour?

Comment: You can check out the StackBlitz linked above and play around with the functionality, it definitely seems to require multiple clicks because of the indication provided by the player's buttons, which only toggle after several clicks, so no @Phaelaxz it doesn't seem to be delayed by a timed buffering. @secan `isPlaying` controls the behaviour of a `Play` / `Pause` button, which toggles between two states, which is why it needs to be `false` - to render a pause `button`.

Comment: Have you tried using `autoPlay` on the `<audio>` element?

Comment: @juliomalves I only want the `Audio` element to play audio when the user clicks on a track, so no.

Comment: @WΔ_ The idea is that the audio will start autoplaying when a new source is set.

Comment: @juliomalves yes that works! That's the exact functionality I was looking for :) However, is there a way to prohibit autoplay on load up? A further problem from this point, is that the toggle fn is incorrectly displaying pause / play half the time, or so :/ I'll take a look at the web-audio-API...

Answer (score 1):

It'll do that, unless you preload your audio data. The `<audio>` element would need to go out, bring the data into the browser, process it, then begin to play. There is a way to try to preload the data. By setting `<audio preload="auto">` it will "attempt" to preload tracks on page load. But, when dynamically setting source, you can't really get that data until you know what the source is. You can get around this, a little, by using the `autoplay` attribute, which will cause the browser to automatically begin fetching the source once it is set. (But then, it will also start playing it right away as well.)